# How to separate Phones and Main outputs

Tags: mixing, source-separation

I have a XENYX Q802USB ([https://www.amazon.com/Behringer-Q802USB-Premium-8-Input-Interface/dp/B008O517IC/ref=sr_1_1?crid=10RQLOK9VIBPJ&keywords=xenyx+802usb&qid=1570741963&s=musical-instruments&sprefix=Xenyx+%2Cmi%2C182&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008O517IC))

I'm trying to get all but the Mic1 to Main Mix, as well as have all inputs go to Phones. I was under the impression that Phones and Main were independent but that isn't the case. Is there a way to make the outputs separate while keeping this mixer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't separate Phones from Main, but there is another way to do what you want, using the FX output.

Use this setup:

- All your inputs go to Main
- open the FX send for all channels except 1 (FX is post-fader, so you can't do it the other way round, with all but 1 on the main and all channels on FX)

The drawback is that the FX send is mono.

Comment: Truthfully I didn't know what the FX was supposed to do but this works. Wish I had a better way to separate without going mono but that's a money problem for later. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. It doesn't look like this desk has any more than two channels out via USB and no monitor section. I don't think you can do what you are seeking to achieve. Phones and Main out are likely to be exactly the same output, just on different connectors.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you are using this for but the only channels that you can assign to main mix and phones separately is the usb/2track. However, you could pan channel one all the way to the right and your left output would be the mix minus channel one. Or you could use the FX send instead of the phones excluding channel one. But again I am not sure how you are using this mixer and if you need a stereo signal anywhere.